# Pentaho web service for .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, reporting-services, report, pentaho

Anyone knows how to run pentaho reports through their web service?

My problem is that I must request reports to pentaho from .Net, if there's any other solution apart from the web service, I really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: @Coconut- I haven't tried their Webservice approach.  But I've used it through Mondrian using Microsoft's ADOMD Client (XMLA approach).  (http://goo.gl/3yJ5C)  Is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho reporting is fully exposed via ordinary URLs. You can query the server for a XML document containing all parameter information necessary to build your own parameter-UI and you can request the resulting documents (PDF, HTML, PNG images etc) via a ordinary HTTP-GET request too. No need for fancy web-services when you can have REST.

For more details: Follow my documentation/guide here:

http://www.sherito.org/2011/06/integrating-phpaspruby-web-applications.html

http://www.sherito.org/2011/06/creating-your-own-parameter-ui-for.html

Comment: What about integrating Single Sign On?
I had been expecting it would allow OpenId/OAuth for authentication and authorisation.
For CAS doesn't the whole website need to use it?
I've been to a talk in which an automated login was done to obtain a cookie, which could then be used. It worked, but it feels very hacky to me.

Comment: The BI-Server uses SpringSecurity, which supports OAuth. You just have to configure it:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/oauth/